# My TestNG assertion is failing. Can someone help here please. What is the mistake I am doing here

Tags: java, automation, automated-tests, testng

The test code being used to simulate the problem.

```java
String response = given()
                    .contentType(contentType)
                    .body(Payload.MultipleMSIDS())
                  .when()
                    .post(baseURI)
                   .thenReturn().asString();

System.out.println(response);
XmlPath xml = new XmlPath(response);

List<String> actualList = xml.getList("svc_result.slia.pos.msid");
System.out.println(actualList);

String[] expectedOutput = new String[]{"[11, 12, 13]",
        "[13, 12, 11]","[11, 13, 12]",
        "[13, 11, 12]","[12, 13, 11]",
        "[12, 11, 13]"};

List<String> expectedOutputList = Arrays.asList(expectedOutput);
System.out.println(expectedOutputList);
Assert.assertTrue(expectedOutputList.Contains(actualList));
```

The test assertion fails with the below details.

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expected :true
Actual   :false
<Click to see difference>
[11, 12, 13] - actualList

[[11, 12, 13],[13, 12, 11],[11, 13, 12],[13, 11, 12],[12, 13, 11],[12, 

11, 13]] - expectedOutputList
```

Comment: I did try with containsAll, same issue.

Answer (score 0):

You get false because when you use `contains` you're asking a list if it contains an object. In your particular case you are asking `expectedOutputList` which is a list of `String`s if it contains another `List`. Since it does not have `List` objects at all (only `String` objects) it returns false.

If you want to test if your list contains **elements of another list** you need to use `containsAll` method like:

```java
expectedOutputList.containsAll(actualList)
```